# C# EntityFramework 6.0 - How to use Where Statement in EntityTypeConfiguration?

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-6, linq-to-entities

I have 2 classes like this:

Parent.cs

```
public class Parent
{
   public int Id {get;set;}
   public virtual ICollection<Child> Children { get; set; }
}
```

Child.cs

```
public class Child
{
    public int Id {get;set;}
    public ItemStatusType ItemStatusTyp { get; set; }
    public int ParentId {get;set;}

    [ForeignKey("ParentId")]
    public virtual Parent Parent { get; set; }
}
```

ItemStatusType.cs

```
public enum ItemStatusType
    {
        Active = 1,
        Deactive = 2,
        Deleted = 3
    }
```

What I want is to somehow retrieve **always** the *active* ones and not the *deleted* ones. Since I am not deleting the record physically, I'm merely updating the `ItemStatusType` to `Deleted` status.

So, when I say `ParentObj.Children` I only wish to retrieve the active ones without further using `Where` condition.

Here is so far what I've done but giving an exception on runtime that I stated afterwards:

```
public class ParentConfiguration : EntityTypeConfiguration<Parent>
{
     public ParentConfiguration()
     {
             HasMany(c => c.Children.Where(p => p.ItemStatusTyp != ItemStatusType.Deleted).ToList())
                .WithRequired(c => c.Parent)
                .HasForeignKey(c => c.ParentId)
                ;
     }
}
```

Runtime Exception:

> The expression 'c => c.Children.Where(p => (Convert(p.ItemStatusTyp)
>   != 3)).ToList()' is not a valid property expression. The expression
>   should represent a property: C#: 't => t.MyProperty'  VB.Net:
>   'Function(t) t.MyProperty'.

I had to use `ToList` after the expression, otherwise it does not compile.

What is the proper what to do what I want?

Thanks in advance,

Comment: You can't to that. Imagine how that would look in the database, that's basically what the configuration is setting up.

Comment: EF has always been barren in such developer-friendly candies. NHibernate is so much more feature rich, I'd almost switch if it wasn't for EF's superior LINQ support. So no, you can't configure a navigation property with a condition. You may want to resort to third-party libraries that provide global filters or find more sophisticated ways to implement soft deletes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot use `Where` or any other logic in fluent property mapping - that's just configuration.

Basically you cannot solve what you need in declarative way.

There are some workarounds which you can use for first-level entities, like implement your own extension(s) `MySet<T>` which will return `.Set<T>.Where(x => x.ItemStatusType != ItemStatusType.Deleted)` and use it everywhere, but that won't solve filtering issue for child collections.

You can go hard way and prepare a separate set of entities to use for selecting data, which basically should be based on database views or stored procedures; you will have to create separate view for every entity, so you will be able to combine selecting in any relations based on these views-entities.

For inserting though you will need to have entities mapped over "real" tables. No sure if it worth it but it might in some cases.

Comment: Thats a shame.. Thank you.. I'll try your suggestion rightaway.

Comment: After trying few more things, I implemented as you said and working beautifully. Thank you.